# Drudgery vs Travail

Tags: meaning, synonyms

Can someone please explain to me the difference between meaning and usage of words *drudgery* and *travail* in nuance?

**Context**: I am writing an email to a mental health worker and I want to emphasize how hard, exhausting, and perhaps even ungrateful her work appears to me.

Brief internet search did not help me much because both [Merriam-Webbster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/drudgery) and [Oxford American Writer's Thesaurus](https://books.google.com/books?id=f_xMAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA509&lpg=PA509&dq=drudgery%20vs%20travail&source=bl&ots=sH3TVqTRdv&sig=DMj3RIM9OBIuae9w8_WeVdpgI6k&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidxdCtutzRAhVJ4WMKHfLXBN4Q6AEIMTAE#v=onepage&q=drudgery%20vs%20travail&f=false) simply list them as synonyms.

Comment: Before you get to the bottom it gives definitions and while similar, they’re different.

Comment: Drudgery is cleaning the toilet.  Travail is using buckets to empty the cesspool.

Comment: @HotLicks So.. would either of them be appropriate to use in the email in my context then?

Comment: That's for you to decide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Travail is more physical in that you may experience pain doing something that causes travail. Drudgery on the other hand is something that's just extremely boring. For example, reading a highly technical book can be a mental drudgery, but it's not travail because doing that does not cause you physical pain. Menial work that involves a lot of physical effort, however, is an example of travail.

Example #1:

> Gosh, this book is such **a drudgery**! I just can't keep reading it anymore.

Example #2:

> Factory workers in third-world countries are vastly underpaid while their hard work is nothing short of pure **travail**.